# How to use de OAuth2 access token with de google api Zend Library for provisioning api

Tags: google-provisioning-api

I am developing a web application, I have the access token and refresh token I got doing my POST requests, I do not understand and do not see in the Google Provisioning API documentation how can i use the Zend library with these tokens, the methods of the Zend library ask me the user and password, not the  tokens, Is there any way to use tokens with the Zend library or only with requests to URLs that gives the api?

Answer (score 0):

There's a full example of doing 3LO in the Zend library available at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/hybrid/index.php. In general, once you have an authorized access token you just need to send it as a header in your requests:

```
Authorization: OAuth TOKEN_GOES_HERE
```

The refresh token is just used to acquire a new access token when the current one expires and isn't used in the actual requests.